# Given two languages L1 and L2, how to calculate L1\L2

Tags: computational-complexity, automata, regular-language

I have a problem with my paper recently. For a given language $L_1$, which is generated by a deterministic finite automaton(DFA) $G$. For another language $L_2$, which is generated by an nondeterministic finite automaton(NFA) $H$. How can I calculate language $L_1\setminus L_2$ based on these two automata? One way I can find is to translate $H$ into a DFA, say $H'$. Then I can construct a new DFA which recognizes $L_1\setminus L_2$ base on $G$ and $H'$. However, the state complexity of NFA to DFA is exponential. I want to know if this problem can be solved with less state complexity. (Sorry for my poor English).

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate $L_1\setminus L_2$"? Its easy to construct an NFA that recognises $L_1\setminus L_2$ because a DFA is trivially an NFA up to change of notation. Is your language finite and do you want to enumerate it?

Comment: @user1001001 The OP clearly states that he is interested in state complexity (see also the tag). Thus the question is: given a language $L_1$ of DFA complexity $n$ and a language $L_2$ of  NFA complexity $m$, what is the NFA complexity of $L_1 \setminus L_2$, in the worst case? And which algorithm should be used?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin What do you mean by  "what is the NFA complexity of $L_1\setminus L_2$"?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin NFA minimization is known to be NP Hard

Comment: @user1001001 I should have said NFA state complexity. I mean the minimal number of states of a NFA accepting $L_1 \setminus L_2$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Seems like that's NP Hard - [NFA Minimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFA_minimization)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @J.-E.Pin said what I meant. I want to construct a deterministic automaton that recognises $L_1\setminus L_2$ based on $G$ and $H$ with minimal number of states. It seems that the state complexity is exponential in the worst case.